# Filtering for max date time within QUERY

Tags: google-sheets

[image]

I have a dataset of the format above. How can I query it such that only the data associated with the max run time is returned?

What I tried was using query to pull this data then ordering by column run time desc and using **limit** to return the max run time. This of course gave me a single value (in cell L1) but when I try to pull this inside a new query (see below formula) I get a blank result (except for the headers).

```
=QUERY(importrange("link","ShipmentOverview!A:I"), "SELECT * where Col9 = '"&$L1&"'")
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this out. this outputs all the rows with the max timestamp in `Col 9` which is `2/24/2023 18:43:17`

```
=lambda(z,filter(z,index(z,,9)=max(index(z,,9))))(importrange("1l_xGjh4YNCANLg-npQWzlXXpQJ3nidC4RzBvR62efuE","ShipmentOverview!A:I"))
```

Comment: It works but how can I edit it so a query applies to the importrange first followed by the lambda? For now the below gives me a formula parse error:



`=lambda(z,filter(z,index(z,,10)=max(index(z,,10))))QUERY(importrange("1l_xGjh4YNCANLg-npQWzlXXpQJ3nidC4RzBvR62efuE","Overview!A:Z"),"Select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col7,Col10,Col14,Col15,Col17",1)`

Comment: Try: `=lambda(z,filter(z,index(z,,10)=max(index(z,,10))))(QUERY(importrange("1l_xGjh4YNCANLg-npQWzlXXpQJ3nidC4RzBvR62efuE","Overview!A:Z"),"Select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col7,Col10,Col14,Col15,Col17",1))`